# Why ArrayStoreException is thrown?

Tags: java

I am trying to write my own ArrayList class.

My code is the following:

```
package test;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.*;

public class MyArrayList {
    private Object[] objects = null;
    private int currentSize = 0;

    public void add(Object obj) {
        increaseSize();
        objects[currentSize++] = obj;
    }

    public Object get(int index) {
        if (currentSize >= index) 
            return objects[index];
        else 
            throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException();
    }

    public void remove(int index) {
        if (currentSize >= index) {
            for (int i = index; i < currentSize; i++) {
                objects[i] = objects[i + 1];
            }
            objects[currentSize--] = null;
        }
        else throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException();
    }

    public int size() {
        return currentSize;
    }

    private void increaseSize() {
        if (objects == null) objects = new Objects[1];
        else objects = Arrays.copyOf(objects, objects.length + 1);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        MyArrayList l = new MyArrayList();
        Integer integ = new Integer(1);
        l.add(integ);
        for (int i = 0; i < l.size(); i++)
        System.out.println("Element " + i + " = " + l.get(i));
    }
}
```

I get ArrayStoreException if I am trying to initilize objects inside increaseSize(). If I am initializing objects at the beginning I don't get that exception anymore.

Can anybody explain me the reason for this ?

Comment: Hint: when creating and throwing exceptions, consider providing a **message** for them. Makes debugging much easier. Now you will just now that some exception was thrown; but you are not providing any of the information that would help debugging (like values of currentSize and index). And: always use { } around your blocks; even when it is just a one-line else thingy.

Comment: `objects = new Objects[1]` - is Object**s** a typo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating an array of type `Objects`:

```
if (objects == null)
    objects = new Objects[1];
```

`Objects` is `java.util.Objects`, as you have imported everything from `java.util`:

```
import java.util.*;
```

While you probably meant an array of `Object`s:

```
if (objects == null)
    objects = new Object[1];
```

The error occurs when you try to store something in the array - unfortunately array types in Java are covariant, which leads to problems like that.

Comment: @AndyTurner: It's an excellent addition, no need to roll it back, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is a very simple error:

you are not creating an array of Object, but of Object**s**.

And that would allow only for storing of Objects objects. So, when you try to add your Integer object, that gives you the ArrayStoreException. Because Integer is not a Objects object. (java.lang.Objects is a utility class that has some static helper methods).

So, simply change to:

```
objects = new Object[1];
```